# Linux : Undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0

Tags: linux, php, sql-server, pdo

When i add the extenstion `extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so`
in php.ini file in linux server with `PHP v7.0` it's giving following error

```
undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0
```

Please Help me.

Thanks

Comment: Fill a bugreport to your distribution. It's their fault.

Comment: @IporSircer but i have create the image of server from amazon. can you please guide me where is error conflict. php.ini and pdo_sqlsrv. i have lot of search.

Comment: @IporSircer all libraries install successfully,  but conflict only this lib

Comment: have you checked this ?
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=55665

Comment: @IporSircer i have also try but same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377338/linux-php-7-0-and-mssql-microsoft-sql

Comment: @NehalDattani pdo_myql is working fine but problem in pdo_sql

Comment: @Nehal Dattani  What is actually problem ?

Comment: Check your config. PHP PDO must be loaded **before** you load any PDO drivers.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `pdo.so` library before all others of the pdo type.

Use this order in php.ini

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
extension=sqlsrv.so
```

After, restart with `service apache2 restart`

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who tried loading `sqlsrv` and `pdo_sqlsrv` on php 7.4 and Ubuntu 18.04, you might need to do the following:

***php 7.4 example:***

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
```

Note: For older versions of PHP you need to specify the version of the module.

***php 7.1 example:***

```
pecl install sqlsrv-5.7.0preview
pecl install pdo_sqlsrv-5.7.0preview
```

Then login as root:

```
sudo su -
printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
```

Note: DO NOT add `extension=sqlsrv.so` and `extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so` in your `php.ini` file. Instead enable the module.

```
sudo phpenmod -v 7.4 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
sudo apachectl restart
```

Now if you load `phpinfo()` in your browser or command line you should now have `pdo_sqlsrv` support enabled.

```
PHP Version 7.4.16

pdo_sqlsrv
pdo_sqlsrv support  enabled
ExtensionVer    5.9.0
Directive   Local Value Master Value
pdo_sqlsrv.client_buffer_max_kb_size    10240   10240
pdo_sqlsrv.log_severity 0   0
pdo_sqlsrv.report_additional_errors 1   1
pdo_sqlsrv.set_locale_info  2   2
```

Comment: +1 for not adding extension line but enabling module with `phpenmod`.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem, type in terminal linux centos 7 :

#### step 1:

```
php --ini
find /etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini
```

edit file and append `extension=sqlsrv.so` `extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so`

**note:** comment `extention extension=sqlsrv.so` , `extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so` on /etc/php.ini

#### step 2:

restart httpd

#### step 3:

```
php -m #you see loaded module
```

Comment: you don't need to reboot the system : just restart the web server